# Custom Row and Column in android Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, viewgroup

[image]How can i develop a grid view with custom row and column ,which means i need to specify the number of row and column of the gridView ;
I have a metrics like data inhand and need to display in the manner they are being for example

> (0,0) (0,1)
>   (1,0) (1,1)

like this formate i need to display also need to scroll horizontally and vertically as the size of data

Answer (score 0):

You can set the number of columns you want in the grid view with `android:numColumns="x"`. To the best of my knowledge there is no way to exactly specify the number of rows for a grid view via xml (or programmatically). You can control the number of rows shown in a grid view by using an `Adapter` class that is populated with `(number of rows you want * number of columns you want)` items

For example, if you want your grid to be 2x2, set `android:numColumns="2"` in xml and populate whatever adapter that serves the grid view with 4 items

Comment: but here i cannot give the num of col greater than the screen size

Comment: i don't understand!! can you give an example?

Comment: plz see the image above